Unable to create a 'DbContext' of type ''. The exception 'The entity type 'Money' requires a primary key to be defined
I have 2 model classes for having price for my other models :
public class ChefFoodPrice
{
    [Key]
    public int ChefFoodPriceId { get; set; }
    public int ChefFoodId { get; set; }
    public int PriceTypeId { get; set; }
    public Money ChefFoodsPrice { get; set; }
    public Money ChefFoodPriceIsDefault { get; set; }
    public DateTime ChefFoodPriceFromDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime ChefFoodPriceToDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime RegisterDate { get; set; }
    public int CreatedUser { get; set; }

    #region Relations
    [ForeignKey("PriceTypeId")]
    public PriceType PriceType { get; set; }
    #endregion
}

And the other model class is:
public class PriceType
{
    [Key]
    public int PriceTypeId { get; set; }
    public string PriceTypeName { get; set; }
    public string PriceTypeCurrency{ get; set; }
    public int PriceTypeIsDefault { get; set; }
    public DateTime RegisterDate { get; set; }
    public int CreatedUser { get; set; }

    #region Relations
    public ICollection<ChefFoodPrice> ChefFoodPrices { get; set; }
    #endregion
}

But after add migration I see this error:

Unable to create a 'DbContext' of type ''. The exception 'The entity type 'Money' requires a primary key to be defined. If you intended to use a keyless entity type, call 'HasNoKey' in 'OnModelCreating'. For more information on keyless entity types, see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2141943.' was thrown while attempting to create an instance. For the different patterns supported at design time, see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=851728

I added this code :
modelBuilder.Entity<ChefFoodPrice>().HasNoKey();

but I still get that error and can not add the migration.
I have set key for Money?
After adding .HasNoKey(), I get this error:

Unable to create a 'DbContext' of type ''. The exception 'The entity type 'Money' requires a primary key to be defined. If you intended to use a keyless entity type, call 'HasNoKey' in 'OnModelCreating'. For more information on keyless entity types, see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2141943.' was thrown while attempting to create an instance. For the different patterns supported at design time, see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=851728

database shows that some of properties should be "Money" type
enter image description here

Where is Money then, show us that?

What is Money? What EF version are you using?

Also the shown code and error has nothing to do with ASP.NET.

@GuruStron as The database that have gave me the type of ChefFoodsPrice property should be "Money"

@DavidG as The database that have gave me the type of ChefFoodsPrice property should be "Money"

The error is complaining about the Money type, it has nothing to do with ChefFoodsPrice

@DavidG I update question for Database. they asked me that ChefFoodsPrice should Money Type, so now what do I do ?

There is no Money type in the framework so you must have created it yourself or imported it from another library by accident. Perhaps you meant to use decimal instead as that make much more sense in this context (as described here)

@maryamforex There's no Money type in .NET. And if "they" mean SQL Server's (very old) legacy money type, no, nothing should be money. The correct type for the last 20+ years is decimal  and the equivalent in .NET is also decimal. Just change the property type to decimal

The only reason to try and specify the money type is if you want to generate the database using EF Migrations from a code-first model. In which case you can specify the TypeName on the property itself

If Money is a custom class, it must be configured as an Entity, or a Complex Type, or have a Value conversion to a type supported by EF for conversion to a database column type.
If you're trying to map to the database type 'Money', the property should be of type Decimal.

Thanks I changed it to decimal , and add migration was successful but with this error: But for this error:
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Model.Validation[30000]
I had to add :  [Column(TypeName = "decimal(18,4)")] or
on modelBuilder add this code:
      modelBuilder.Entity<ChefFoodPrice>().Property(p => p.ChefFoodsPrice).HasColumnType("decimal(18,4)");

